# Angular google maps dynamic polyline with a lot of points

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I have a polyline which can contain a lot of points, and also can be changed according to the user behavior, I am currently using [Angular Google maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps) 1.2.x and employment strategy is as follows:

```
 myService.getPoints(id)
     .success(function(data){
          //in other controller have $scope.p = pService
          pService.Polyline = [];

          for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
              var p = {
                  latitde : data.Latitudefield,
                  longitude : data.Longitudefield
               }
               pService.Polyline.push(p);
          }
     })
```

This works, but when the number of points is a lot (about 4000 points or more), the application becomes very slow, what strategy can be used to handle this?

Comment: You should get an undefined error with your code : 
var p = {...};
p.Service.Polyline.push(p);

Comment: oh, ty , that is just a example , i will edit code.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solve this issue?

Comment: i used another strategy , like pagination.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it to get a faster rendering.

```
   $scope.trackings = [{
        id: 1,
        geotracks: [{
            latitude: 23.0,
            longitude: 72.58
        }, {
            latitude: 23.1,
            longitude: 72.58
        }]
    }, {
        id: 2,
        geotracks: [{
            latitude: 24.0,
            longitude: 72.58
        }, {
            latitude: 23.1,
            longitude: 71.58
        }]
    }];

<div class="row" ng-if="map.show">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
        <ui-gmap-polylines models="trackings" path="'geotracks'" static="true"></ui-gmap-polylines>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

The key here is static="true". I had to wrap it all in a ng-if="map.show" that I set true when data is ready, because the static keyword makes it, well, static (and not async). Hope this helps :)

Ref: http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/polylines

> **static**: Boolean property which indicates that the Polyline coordinates are static.(I.e. will not change).
>
> Declaring a static path will improve the performance of the directive as it does not need to monitor every coordinate in the path for changes during the Angular $digest cycle.
>
> Notes:
>
> Declaring a static path implies that it is not editable. As a result, the editable parameter will be ignored.
>
> For static paths, the path attribute will watched by reference so the path may be changed in its entirety and the map will update.
>
> Changes to the static declaration are ignored after the directive is instantiated. (NOT WATCHED)

Comment: This makes a massive difference.  It can also be used for a single polyline.  To clarify if you replace a line it will still update, it just wont work if you modify a single point within that line.